# Accessing Image pixel by pixel in Java

Tags: java

Is there any inbuilt java API or class library for accessing pixels in a given image?
What I am planning to do is search one image inside another image. 
For example : img1 is 24x24px , img2 is 1024x768px
assume that a symbol, similar to img1 may exists in img2 . Now I want to get X and Y coordinates of the symbol which is similar to the img1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is, if you have your image as a `BufferedImage` then use the `getRGB(int x, int y)` method to get the value of the pixel at the position (x, y).

See the API documentation of [`java.awt.image.BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`getRGB(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) method in the Java  `BufferedImage` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, you can call `getRGB()`, which returns a array of `int`s containing the color values of each pixel.

If you Image is not an instance of `BufferedImage`, you can use `java.awt.image.PixelGrabber` to get the same result, using the `setPixels()` method.